# ember/handlebars template using dynamic string as variable name

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a weird situation where I need to use a dynamic string as a variable name in a handlebars loop in my Ember application.

I have a table with some coffee drinks. Let's say I have a couple variables in my controller called "customDrinksList", "customDrink1", and "customDrink2".

customDrinksList is an array with strings `["customDrink1", "customDrink2"]`.
customDrink1 and customDrink2 are arrays of drink objects that come from my ember-data store.

```
{{#each customDrink in customDrinksList}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{customDrink}}</td>
    {{#each drink in customDrink}}
      ...
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

When I do this, `customDrink` is just the string but in the `{{#each drink in customDrink}}` statement I want to use the variable with that string name instead of using the actual string.

When I substitute in the variable name (such as customDrink1) it returns the drinks as I'm looking for, but I need to have the variable names in customDrinksList be looped through.

Not sure if this is possible since I haven't been able to find any solutions or maybe I should be taking another approach. Any suggestions welcome.

This project is using Ember 1.13.x

Comment: Why `customDrinksList` can not just be an array, containing arrays of drink objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from within the template. Consider adding a computed property in the controller/component etc.:

```
customDrinksListValues: Ember.computed.map(
  'customDrinksList', 
  function(drink) { return this.get(drink); })
```